# A phrase/preposition for monitoring something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, prepositional-phrases

I want to use the sentence 1

> They monitor the security of the device.

and make the sentence 2

> I don't know how they monitor the device ---- the security.

What should I put in the blank?

The options I have in mind and have been used here or there are "in terms of", "concerning" and "regarding".

Are any of this options correct in such sentences? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not "they monitor the device's secuity"? Sentence 1 does not say they monitor the device: they monitor the security of the device. Trying to say they monitor the device actually changes the sentence quite significantly.

Comment: Monitor the device for security.

Comment: @moonstar2001 A good suggestion. That is one of the meanings of "for". I think your comment can be suggested as an answer.

Comment: @sasan Done :-)

Comment: @Sasan, your sentence sounds like the device is being stored in a vault, and the monitors are making sure no one steals it. If you mean the device is operating and the monitors are plugged in and are making sure no one uses it to steal something else, you need to start all over again.

Answer (score 1):

"Monitor the device for security. " fits your requirement.